# Angular Material - Form is getting invalid, when mat datepicker model value is less than min date

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using mat datepicker on my form. I am inserting some records. This works fine with form validation. But when the same record I am trying to update, then my form show invalid. This is due to the date is invalid.

**Case when form shows invalid - When min date is greater than model value.**

Why this is happening? Is this default behaviour? How to make it work?

**component.html**

```
 <form class="form-container" #pointAllocationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <div class="start-date">
        <label class="required"><strong>Start Date : </strong></label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatepicker" [min]="minDate" placeholder="Choose a date" name="StartDate"
            [(ngModel)]="myDate" #StartDate="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="setEndDate($event)" required>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #startDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error *ngIf="StartDate.invalid && (StartDate.dirty || StartDate.touched)">Please enter a valid date.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
</mat-form-field>
       <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="pointAllocationForm.invalid">
          Update Points </button>
  </form>
```

component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-min-max-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-min-max-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-min-max-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerMinMaxExample {
  minDate = new Date();
  myDate = new Date(2018, 9, 10);
}
```

Comment: This is because when you try to edit your form your min date will be current date and your start date which is stored and fetched back at the time of edit will be lower then current date that is why it was showing validation error. if you are not allowing to edit start date at the time of update you can disable that field.

Comment: @Dipal I want to allow start date at the time of update.

Comment: You can do one thing. You are already not allowing past date so whenever any one try to update form you can set start date by conditioning like if start date < current date then  you will update start date with your current date .

Comment: @DIpal But what if I want to update other fields and don't want to start date. It should not update my existing start date.

Comment: any solution on that? I'd also like to just limit the datepicker for new inputs to the future, not the values which have been existing for a while. I think this datepicker should just not affect the form validation. Of course it is consistent but it is a problem whenever the value is filled back into the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution which is working for my case:

```
template: [min]="formGroup.get('date').value ? formGroup.get('date').value : todayDate"
in code: todayDate = new Date();
```

Means, I set the date from backend as min, otherwise today. When a date was picked, it will never be less than the originally given one. But this requires of course that the given date is valid.

Comment: Yes. it can, but I want to disable all dates before today's date. This is the validation I want. By this approach, user can select a date before today's date.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but if you call setErrors(null) function from FormComponent after populating your formControl it becomes valid